# Replace a second value based on a condition on succesive first value on a dataframe R

Tags: r

Actually I have a dataframe with 2 values:

```r
v1<- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,2,1,1,0,1,0,2)
v2<- c(5,5,10,-1,-5,9,7,6,1,5,3,-4,7,-6,-3,-1,7,1,5,3)
df<- data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2)

> df
   v1 v2
1   1  5
2   1  5
3   1 10
4   0 -1
5   0 -5
6   1  9
7   1  7
8   2  6
9   2  1
10  2  5
11  0  3
12  0 -4
13  0  7
14  2 -6
15  1 -3
16  1 -1
17  0  7
18  1  1
19  0  5
20  2  3​
```

What I'm trying to do is **replacing values on value V2**, based on the fact that : 
If there is **successive 0 on V1** (only **successive 0** so 1,0,1 wont count but 1,0,0,1 will count and so on), **all V2 will be equal to the first V2 value where 0 occures in V1**.

**For example:**

```r
> df[3:6,]
  v1 v2
3  1 10
4  0 -1
5  0 -5
6  1  9

#Must become 

> df[3:6,]
  v1 v2
3  1 10
4  0 -1
5  0 -1
6  1  9
```

Or also :

```r
> df[10:14,]
   v1 v2
10  2  5
11  0  3
12  0 -4
13  0  7
14  2 -6

#Must become 


> df[10:14,]
   v1 v2
10  2  5
11  0  3
12  0  3
13  0  3
14  2 -6​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the group with `rleid` (from `data.table`) and `replace` 'v2' with the `first` value of 'v2' only when `all` the values in 'v1' are 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(v1)) %>%
   mutate(v2 = if(all(v1 == 0)) first(v2) else v2) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 20 x 2
#      v1    v2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     5
# 2     1     5
# 3     1    10
# 4     0    -1
# 5     0    -1
# 6     1     9
# 7     1     7
# 8     2     6
# 9     2     1
#10     2     5
#11     0     3
#12     0     3
#13     0     3
#14     2    -6
#15     1    -3
#16     1    -1
#17     0     7
#18     1     1
#19     0     5
#20     2     3
```

---

Or using `data.table` (from @IceCreamToucan's comments)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, v2 := if(first(v1) == 0) first(v2) else v2, rleid(v1)]
```

Comment: Or `setDT(df)[, v2 := if(first(v1) == 0) first(v2) else v2, rleid(v1)]` in data.table. This example really shows how dropping groups by default and having the ability to group by columns not in your data can simplify things vs dplyr :)

Comment: thats also a great solution @IceCreamToucan thanks a lot

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, please If I have 3 values to set do I have to do them separately or here is a nice way?
setDT(df)[, v2 := if(first(v1) == 0) first(v2) else v2, rleid(v1)]
setDT(df)[, v3 := if(first(v1) == 0) first(v3) else v3, rleid(v1)]
setDT(df)[, v4 := if(first(v1) == 0) first(v4) else v4, rleid(v1)]

Comment: You can use lapply. Also, you only need to `setDT` once. (new line wherever you see a `;`) `setDT(df);
cols <- grep('v[2-4]', names(df), val = T);
df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) if(first(v1) == 0) first(x) else x),
   rleid(v1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an solution with `base R`, where `rle()` and `split()` are used:

```
dfs <- split(df,findInterval(1:nrow(df),cumsum((r <- with(df,rle(v1)))$lengths),left.open = T))
df <- Reduce(rbind,{dfs[r$values==0] <- Map(function(x) {x[2]<-head(x[2],1);x},dfs[r$values==0]);dfs})
```

which gives

```
> df
   v1 v2
1   1  5
2   1  5
3   1 10
4   0 -1
5   0 -1
6   1  9
7   1  7
8   2  6
9   2  1
10  2  5
11  0  3
12  0  3
13  0  3
14  2 -6
15  1 -3
16  1 -1
17  0  7
18  1  1
19  0  5
20  2  3
```

**DATA**

```
v1<- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,2,1,1,0,1,0,2)
v2<- c(5,5,10,-1,-5,9,7,6,1,5,3,-4,7,-6,-3,-1,7,1,5,3)
df<- data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2)
```